# wordpress custom contact form html + php inside page

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

hi everybody i have my contact form ready in html and php (2 different files one html and one php file) and i want to use it in a worpress page.
the user fills the form, selects support department answers the captcha and presses submit button. the form sends all the form data through email to the administrator, a thank you email to the user and redirects to a thank you page.
the html form is

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer>         </script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
</head>
 <i>Use the form to get in touch with us.</i>


<form action="form.php"  method="POST">

<strong>Name:*</strong>

<input style="width:300px;" name="username" type="text" required />

<strong>E-mail Adress:*</strong>

<input style="width:300px;" name="useremail" type="text" required />

<strong>Subject:*</strong>

<input style="width:300px;" name="usersubject" type="text" required />

<strong>Message:*</strong>

<textarea style="width:300px;" cols="40" name="usermessage" rows="5"     required></textarea>

<strong>Select Support Department </strong>

<select  name="support">
<option style="width:200px;" value="" >Choose Service</option>
<option style="width:200px;" value="support@xxxxxxxx.com"         required>Technical support</option>
<option style="width:200px;" value="sales@xxxxxxxxxx.com"     required>Sales</option>
<option style="width:200px;" value="info@xxxxxxxxxxx.com" required>Press</option>
<option style="width:200px;" value="info@xxxxxxxxxxx.com" required>Other</option>
</select>

//recaptcha
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-    sitekey="------my site key---------"></div>

<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>

//it redirects when you hit submit
<?php
 if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
header("Location:http://xxxxxxxxx.com/thank-you-messasge/");
}
?>
</form>

</html>
</body>
```

my form.php is

```
<?
    //set up the message for administrator
$msg="Name:".$_POST["username"]."\n";
$msg .="E-mail:".$_POST["useremail"]."\n";
$msg .="Subject:".$_POST["usersubject"]."\n";
$msg .="Usermessage:".$_POST["usermessage"]."\n";

//set up message for customer

$msg_customer="We received your request and we will answer you within     24 hours.";
$msg_customer.="\n"."xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

//set up the email for the administrator
$recipient=$_POST["support"];
$subject= "Support Contact Form ";
$mailheaders="From: xxxxxxxx sales@xxxxxxxxx.com \n";

//set up the email for the customer
$recipient_customer=$_POST["useremail"];
$subject_customer= "Support Contact Form ";
$mailheaders_customer="From: xxxxxxxxxx sales@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com \n";
//send the emails
mail($recipient,$subject,$msg, $mailheaders);
mail($recipient_customer,$subject_customer,$msg_customer,     $mailheaders_customer);

?>
```

i want this form to appear in one page and be able to run the php code when the submit button is pressed.
i cannot run the form.php file even if i save it on the root directory.
it seems i am loosing something 
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot your form, press F12 in your browser to access the developer tools menu, and take a look at what happens on the Network panel when you submit the form. This should give you some clues about what is failing.

Also, you should not be using unfiltered `$_POST` variables directly, e.g.:

```
$name = sprintf("Name:%s\n", filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) );
```

Comment: hi .maybe i didnt make my self clear. this is a working html form with a working php file that when i test it locally works fine. the question is how could i manage to use it in a wordpress page? i hope this doesn't go outside the scope of stackoverflow since it's my first post. i found a lot of post about wordpress though none of them was helpfull.

Comment: You could just copy and paste the form HTML into a `code` view of the page, but TinyMCE has a way of messing up complex HTML. A better wau is to create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) (copy an existing template from your theme) with your form code. You could also [make a shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode) to insert your code.

Comment: ok. i am using the text mode of the editor so this way i dont get my code stripped. but about the:<code><form action="form.php"  method="POST"> </code>where should i place the form.php file?

Answer (score -1):

i found out the way:
i copy/pasted the html form inside the page code view and i linked absolutely to my php file
   `<form action="http://example.com/php_file_directory/form.php"  method="POST">`